# AngularJS - Use data returned by a service in the controller and the view to populate dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/settingsStyles/generalSettings.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="assignment3App">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <div class="container">
        <h2>General Settings</h2>            
        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="success">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Language:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Gmail display language:
                  <select ng-controller = "callServ as langData">
                      <option ng-click = "langData.callServ()"> language </option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="danger">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Phone numbers:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Default country code:</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="info">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Maximum page size: </td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9"> Show conversations per page 
                  <aside> Show contacts per page </aside>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="success">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Default reply behavior:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Reply: 
                  <aside> Reply all:  </aside>
            </tr>

            <tr class="danger">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Undo Send:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Enable Undo Send 
                  <aside> Send cancellation period:  </aside>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="info">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Signature:  </td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9"> No signature</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/extractData.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/fetchData.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller `dropdown.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var callServ = function (getData) {
        getData.getLanguages();
        };

    angular.module('assignment3App')
      .controller ('callServ', ['getData', callServ]);      
}());
```

Service `extractData.js` that calls another service to obtain the json data

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var getData = function (fetchDataService) {
      this.getLanguages = function() {

             fetchDataService.getContent()
              .then(function (returnedData) {
                    console.log(returnedData.data.languages[0]);
                  });
              };   
      };    

      angular.module('assignment3App')
        .service ('getData', ['fetchDataService', getData]);
}());
```

Service that fetches the JSON data `fetchData.js`:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var fetchDataService = function($http) {
      this.getContent = function() {
        return $http({
            method : 'get',
            url : '../../data/languages.json'
          });
      };
  };

  angular.module('assignment3App')
    .service ('fetchDataService', fetchDataService);
}());
```

I want to populate the languages from the JSON file as options in the select menu.

language.json

```
{
    "languages": [
        "Afrikaans",
        "Albanian",
        "Arabic",
        "Armenian",
        "Basque",
        "Bengali",
        "Catalan",
        "Cambodian",
        "Chinese (Mandarin)",
        "German",
        "Greek",
        "Gujarati",
        "Hebrew",
        "Icelandic" ,
        "Maori" ,
        "Marathi",
        "Mongolian",
        "Serbian",
        "Slovak",
        "Slovenian",
        "Spanish",
        "Swahili",
        "Swedish" ,
        "Tamil" ,
        "Tatar" ,
        "Telugu"
    ] 
}
```

I have the following questions:

1) How to access the `returnedData` variable in the file `extractData.js` in the controller? 
 
2) How to use ng-repeat on the option element in `index.html` to show all languages in the dropdown? Should I use $index to get each element of the JSON array in the view? 
 
3) Depending on the language the user selects, when he clicks on the submit button, I want the selected language to be stored in another service. Does anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE - Questions 2**

I was able to populate the dropdown menu using `ng-options`. In my controller, I changed the `languages` variable to hold only the array of `languages`. Below are my updated `index.html` and controller.

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Settings Page </title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
    <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/settingsStyles/generalSettings.css">

  </head>
  <body ng-app="assignment3App">
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->

    <div class="container">
        <h3>General Settings</h3>      

        <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="success" ng-controller = "callServ">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Language:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Gmail display language:
                  <select ng-model = "selectedLang" ng-options="language for language in languages">
                      <option value = ""> Choose a language </option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="danger">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Phone numbers:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">Default country code:
                  <select>
                      <option> Country code </option>
                  </select>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="info">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Maximum page size: </td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9"> Show conversations per page 
                  <select>
                      <option> 10 </option>
                  </select>

                  <aside id = "pageSize"> Show contacts per page 
                        <select>
                            <option> 20 </option>
                        </select>
                  </aside>

              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="success">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Default reply behavior:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9">
                  <input type = "radio" name = "replySetting" id = "reply" checked> 
                  <label for="reply"> Reply </label>

                  <aside> 
                        <input type = "radio" name = "replySetting" id = "replyAll"> 
                        <label for="replyAll"> Reply all</label> 
                  </aside>
            </tr>

            <tr class="danger">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Undo Send:</td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9" ng-controller = "undoSendController as undoSend">
                  <input type = "checkbox" id = "undoSend" ng-click = "undoSend.displayCancelPeriod()"> 
                  <label for="undoSend"> Enable Undo Send  </label> 

                  <aside ng-show = "undoSend.cancelPeriod" ng-cloak> Send cancellation period:  
                      <select>
                            <option> 10 </option>
                      </select>
                  </aside>
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="info" ng-controller = "signatureController as signature">
              <td class = "col-xs-3">Signature:  </td>
              <td class = "col-xs-9"> 
                  <input type = "radio" name = "signature" ng-click = "signature.disableTextarea()" id = "noSignature" checked> 
                  <label for="noSignature"> No signature </label> 
                    <div class="span12" >
                          <input type = "radio" name = "signature" ng-click = "signature.enableTextarea()" id = "signature">
                          <textarea class="field span6" id="textarea" rows="6" cols = "50" placeholder="Enter a signature" ng-disabled = "signature.typeSignature"></textarea>
                    </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
     <script>
       !function(A,n,g,u,l,a,r){A.GoogleAnalyticsObject=l,A[l]=A[l]||function(){
       (A[l].q=A[l].q||[]).push(arguments)},A[l].l=+new Date,a=n.createElement(g),
       r=n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0],a.src=u,r.parentNode.insertBefore(a,r)
       }(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

       ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
       ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/dropdown.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/undoSend.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/signature.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/promise.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/callJson.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

`dropdown.js`

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var callServ = function (getData, $scope) {
        getData.getLanguages()
            .then(function(data){
                    $scope.languages = data.languages;
        });
    };

    angular.module('assignment3App')
      .controller ('callServ', ['getData', '$scope', callServ]);        
}());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you would return the data from your service using the promise:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var getData = function (fetchDataService) {
      this.getLanguages = function() {

             return fetchDataService.getContent()
              .then(function (returnedData) {
                    return returnedData.data;
                    //console.log(returnedData.data.languages[0]);
                  });
              };   
      };    

      angular.module('assignment3App')
        .service ('getData', ['fetchDataService', getData]);
}());
```

Then you would get the data from the returned promise and add it to the scope in your controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    //this will be the select value
    $scope.selectedLanguage = '';

    $scope.setLanguage = function(){
        //this is called when the submit button is clicked
        yourService.languageChanged($scope.selectedLanguage);
    };

    var callServ = function (getData) {
        getData.getLanguages().then(function(data){
            //data = returnedData.data
            $scope.languages = data;
        });
    };

    angular.module('assignment3App')
      .controller ('callServ', ['getData', callServ]);      
}());
```

Then you can attach the options to the select [using ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```
<select ng-options="language for language in languages"
    ng-model="selectedLanguage">
</select>
<button type="button" ng-click="setLanguage()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful. However, I still have a problem. I do not get any error in the console, but the options are not populating. Do you have any input on this?

Comment: This is the select element. `<select ng-controller = "callServ" ng-options = "language for language in languages"></select>`.

Comment: ng-options are pretty weird, and very awkward to use. I always have to mess around with the syntax to get things to output. Also it would depend on the type of data you are getting back. If you have an array of objects you would have to specify the key that you want to be visible etc

Comment: I changed `ng-options` and now it is giving me undefined in the dropdown menu. `<select ng-model = "selectedLang" ng-options="language.languages for language in languages"></select>`. Earlier it was not displaying anything in the dropdown

Comment: I figured it out. I will update my question, so that others can understand as well. Thanks for your help.